# Converting [NSNetservice addresses] to ip address string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsnetservice

This question was already asked here:
[NSNetservice IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720316/nsnetservice-ip-address)

and here:
[iPhone: Bonjour NSNetService IP address and port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938521/iphone-bonjour-nsnetservice-ip-address-and-port)

I've used both of those to get where I'm at now. My  problem is the following method I have doesn't quite work:

```
- (NSString *)getStringFromAddressData:(NSData *)dataIn {
    struct sockaddr_in  *socketAddress = nil;
    NSString            *ipString = nil;

    socketAddress = (struct sockaddr_in *)[dataIn bytes];
    ipString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%s",
                inet_ntoa(socketAddress->sin_addr)];  ///problem here
    return ipString;
}
```

This gives a build error saying both "Dereferencing pointer to incomplete type" and "Implicit declaration of function 'inet_ntoa'" on the same line.

I've checked and I don't think I'm missing some type of framework to get `inet_ntoa` to work. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? thanks.

Comment: Acctually inet_ntoa is depreciated, use inet_ntop instead!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you're getting implicit declaration of inet_ntoa, you probably need

```
 #include <arpa/inet.h>
```

(You can man inet_ntoa to get this info and read more about that function)

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you very much for the speedy response!

Answer (score 3):

FWIW I've posted an updated code snippet for handling NSNetService address resolution over at

[iPhone: Bonjour NSNetService IP address and port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938521/iphone-bonjour-nsnetservice-ip-address-and-port/4976808#4976808).